# Can I terminate a program with System.exit() without closing GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, terminate

I have a program that runs events based on values read from a text file. I set up a GUI that has a start button to launch the program running. If there is a terminate event in the text file then I shut the program down using 'System.exit(0);'. The only problem is that I don't want the GUI to close, I just want the program to stop running. Is there an easy way to keep the GUI open?  I have a feeling this is a stupid question. Please excuse me if it is, as I am new to programming and very new to GUI's.

Comment: What is the point of the GUI being open if the program doesn't run. Can you please clarify your requirements?

Comment: Your "program" launches the GUI, which displays the start button, which in turn launches "something else".  You kill the program - then you kill your GUI, too.  Q: What is this "something else" that happens when you click "Start"?

Comment: **"If there is a terminate event in the text file"** - Can you elaborate on this, so we can better understand your requirements

Comment: @peeskillet - Events are output to a JTextArea in the GUI. If a Terminate event is read from the file then I want the program to stop and no more events read from the file. I want the GUI to stay open so I can make a restart button that will restart the program.

Comment: looks to me like you mistake a function for a program then. What if you use `return` instead of `System.exit(0)`?

Answer (score 3):

If you run whatever you are doing on one thread, and the gui on another, just terminate the other thread.
Try to make your program a Runnable and then run it with an Executor, that'll be a simple solution.
For example you could call a method on your main thread from the worker to see if it should terminate. Avoid terminating threads by force as a general advice.

Comment: I have very little experience with threads. Is it possible to create the thread for the GUI from the constructor where I instantiate the GUI objecdt: public Controls() { new ControlsGUI(this); }

Comment: Yes, but you might want to do that when the user clicks the [Start some action] button to check if all the data you need for the thread to start is there.

Answer (score 1):

Your GUI is part of your program itself. Calling `System.exit(0)` will stop the JVM along with your program.